# Dúvida referente a estrutura do arquivo docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker

Tenho o seguinte arquivo **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: senha_root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database_name
    command: ['--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/tmp:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  web:
    container_name: web
    image: web_dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-web
    volumes:
      - ./projeto/:/var/www
      - ./apache/:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
    working_dir: /var/www
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 3000:3000
      - 3001:3001
```

Lendo alguns posts observei que normalmente é adicionada instrução networks, ficando desta forma:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: senha_root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database_name
    command: ['--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
    networks:
      - dev
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/tmp:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  web:
    container_name: web
    image: web_dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-web
    volumes:
      - ./projeto/:/var/www
      - ./apache/:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
    working_dir: /var/www
    networks:
      - dev
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 3000:3000
      - 3001:3001
  networks:
      dev:
```

Pelo que pude entender, ao declarar a instrução networks conforme acima, estou criando uma nova interface de rede, entretanto, não compreendi qual a real explicação e necessidade disso, alguma explicação?

E por qual motivo normalmente repete a palavra network no final do arquivo, isso é para expor a rede?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geralmente você cria redes no docker quando você quer controlar melhor como seus containers vão se comunicar entre si - qual pode conversar com qual, usar o nome do host ao invés do IP etc. Quando usamos o docker-compose ele automaticamente cria uma rede para os serviços contidos ali, mas se você tiver necessidade de configurar alguma coisa, criar mais de uma ou mesmo utilizar alguma que já exista, você pode utilizando estas definições de rede.

A razão de você especificar "duas vezes" é que em cada ponto do arquivo você está fazendo uma coisa diferente.

Quando você define "networks" no nível raiz, está criando e configurando as redes que você pretende usar. Quando coloca dentro dos services está especificando em quais redes o container irá entrar.

Você pode encontrar mais informações a respeito na [documentação](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks) do docker-compose.

Comment: Show de bola. Essa explicação tirou a dúvida que eu tinha. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Os arquivos do docker compose seguem a seguinte lógica: 
1) Os arquivos são analisados em profundidade e não de cima para baixo, isso significa que você pode trocar a ordem das coisas, seja primeiro networks (global) e depois (services) ou o contrário, o que é mais comum.

2) Os níveis mais elevados efetivamente definem coisas, no seu caso network, mas o mesmo acontece com volumes. No nível mais elevado (raiz) você efetivamente constrói ou referencia uma rede ou um volume, para que, somente então, possa usá-las em seus services.

Embora possa parecer redundante, analise as construções mais complexas como por exemplo:

```
networks:

  minhanet1:
    external:true

  minhanet2:
    driver:bridge

  minhanet3:
    driver:overlay

  minhanet4:
    driver:overlay

  app_net:
    driver: bridge
    enable_ipv6: true
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
      - subnet: 2001:3984:3989::/64
```

Isso tudo é descrito no nível mais elevado, raiz, assim, uma vez referenciado ou descrito, você pode usar normalmente em seus services.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para melhor esclarecer minha dúvida